# Could not authenticate error on Twitter when adding include_email parameter

Tags: python, twitter, flask, twitter-oauth

I'm using [Miguel Grinberg's example](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/oauth-authentication-with-flask) of allowing users to login via Twitter and Flask-Login. It works fine, but when I request for user's email (?include_email=true), I get the following error:

`{u'errors': [{u'message': u'Could not authenticate you.', u'code': 32}]}`

On apps.twitter.com, I have enabled *Request email addresses from users*. I can see the app requesting for email on the consent screen. I also tried regenerating my Consumer Key and Consumer Secret, but no luck.

Here's the code for authenticating with Twitter:

```
class TwitterSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TwitterSignIn, self).__init__('twitter')
        self.service = OAuth1Service(
            name='twitter',
            consumer_key=self.consumer_id,
            consumer_secret=self.consumer_secret,
            request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate',
            access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'
        )

    def authorize(self):
        request_token = self.service.get_request_token(
            params={'oauth_callback': self.get_callback_url()}
        )
        session['request_token'] = request_token
        return redirect(self.service.get_authorize_url(request_token[0]))

    def callback(self):
        request_token = session.pop('request_token')
        if 'oauth_verifier' not in request.args:
            return None, None, None
        oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
            request_token[0],
            request_token[1],
            data={'oauth_verifier': request.args['oauth_verifier']}
        )
        network = 'twitter'
        me = oauth_session.get('account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true').json()
        social_id = 'twitter$' + str(me.get('id'))
        username = me.get('screen_name')
        email = me.get('email')
        return social_id, username, email
```

Comment: Changing to `me = oauth_session.get("account/verify_credentials.json", params={'include_email': 'true'}).json()` resolved the issue. Note: true has to be sent as string.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Just make sure it's detailed and well documented for the next soul that has this issue. :)